# Navigation mapping issues in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:

User table (has link to user details)
User details table (holds links to various detail tables)

but am getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a relationship between 'Address.ClientDetails' and 'ClientDetails.ResidentialAddress', because there already is a relationship between 'ClientDetails.PostalAddress' and 'Address.ClientDetails'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.
```

I understand this problem would occur if entity framework had no way to identify which address to link to each address - but i thought i take care of that by specifying 2 links in the model and then each key map in the mapping class. Any help would be great!

my Client model and mapping looks as follows:

```
public class Client : BaseEntity
    {
        public ClientDetails ApplicantDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ClientDetails.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ClientType == Enums.ClientType.Applicant.ToString());
            }
        }

    public ClientDetails SpouseDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ClientDetails.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ClientType == Enums.ClientType.Spouse.ToString());
        }
    }
    public ICollection<ClientDetails> ClientDetails { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BankDetails> BankDetails { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Expenses> Expenses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Obligation> Obligations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document.Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public virtual Workflow.Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
```

Mapping

```
public class ClientMapping: IEntityTypeConfiguration<Entities.Client.Client>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Entities.Client.Client> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Client");
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        builder.HasMany(e => e.ClientDetails).WithOne(e => e.Client).HasForeignKey(e => e.ClientId);
        builder.HasMany(e => e.Documents).WithOne(e => e.Client).HasForeignKey(e => e.ClientId);
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Workflow).WithOne(e => e.Client).HasForeignKey<Entities.Workflow.Workflow>(e => e.ClientId);
        builder.HasMany(e => e.Obligations).WithOne(e => e.Client).HasForeignKey(e => e.ClientId);
        builder.HasMany(e => e.Expenses).WithOne(e => e.Client).HasForeignKey(e => e.ClientId);
        builder.HasMany(e => e.Budgets).WithOne(e => e.Client).HasForeignKey(e => e.ClientId);
        builder.HasMany(e => e.BankDetails).WithOne(e => e.Client).HasForeignKey(e => e.ClientId);

        builder.Ignore(e => e.ApplicantDetails);
        builder.Ignore(e => e.SpouseDetails);
    }
}
```

Client Details and mapping

```
public class ClientDetails
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int PersonalDetailsId { get; set; }
        public int EmployerId { get; set; }
        public int ResidentialAddressId { get; set; }
        public int PostalAddressId { get; set; }
        public int IncomeId { get; set; }
        public string ClientType { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
        public virtual PersonalDetails PersonalDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual Employer Employer { get; set; }
        public virtual Address ResidentialAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual Address PostalAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual Income Income { get; set; }
    }
```

mapping

```
public class ClientDetailsMapping : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Entities.Client.ClientDetails>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ClientDetails> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("ClientDetails");
            builder.HasKey(e => new { e.IncomeId, e.PersonalDetailsId, e.ClientId, e.PostalAddressId, e.ResidentialAddressId } );
            builder.HasOne(e => e.Income).WithOne(e => e.ClientDetails).HasForeignKey<ClientDetails>(e => e.IncomeId);
            builder.HasOne(e => e.PostalAddress).WithOne(e => e.ClientDetails).HasForeignKey<ClientDetails>(e => e.PostalAddressId);
            builder.HasOne(e => e.ResidentialAddress).WithOne(e => e.ClientDetails).HasForeignKey<ClientDetails>(e => e.ResidentialAddressId);
            builder.HasOne(e => e.Employer).WithOne(e => e.ClientDetails).HasForeignKey<ClientDetails>(e => e.EmployerId);
            builder.HasOne(e => e.PersonalDetails).WithOne(e => e.ClientDetails).HasForeignKey<ClientDetails>(e => e.PersonalDetailsId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this post:

[ef core - two one to one on one principal key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219379/ef-core-two-one-to-one-on-one-principal-key)

Ended up implementing solution 3, client details now has a collection of addresses (which have an address type linked), I then added an address getter on the client details to get the address I want at a later time. Everything seems to work correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to delete the content of "WithOne"?

try this:

```
builder.HasOne(e => e.PostalAddress).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ClientDetails>(e => e.PostalAddressId);
builder.HasOne(e => e.ResidentialAddress).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ClientDetails>(e => e.ResidentialAddressId);
```